# duplicate key value violates unique constraint .... Django error

Tags: python, django, model, key, unique

I am trying to make a 'get' query on a model. The parameters that i'm using to query the model are foreign keys(both of them).
The models looks something like this...

```
class model_1(models.Model):
   field_1  =  models.ForeignKey(model_2)
   field_2  =  models.CharField(max_length = 512)
   field_3 = models.ForeignKey(model_3)

   class Meta:
      unique_together = ("field_1", "field_3")
```

and i'm trying to run this query

```
m = model_1.objects.get(field_1 = 'something', field_2 = 'something_1')
```

But it throws back an error `duplicate key value violates unique constraint...` along with `DETAIL:  Key (model_1_id, model_3_id)=(1339, 5) already exists`

I'm not able to understand why the error is on duplicate keys when I'm trying to read the entries. It would have made sense to me if I were trying to insert a new record in it and had conflicting keys.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think django throws some exceptions while calling a `get()` query method

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a unique index on (field_1, field_3) which already have duplicate data.
Please check your data there must be 2 rows with the same value of field_1 and field_3 ie.(1339, 5), which is violating the unique constraint.

Comment: I did! There are no duplicate entries in the database.

Comment: I deleted all the the rows in the model and created just a single row that would match the query. It still throws the same error.  What surprise me is `get` query throwing duplicate key value error. It is a search query and not an insert query.

Comment: get query doesn't throw duplicate key value error. you might be inserting the same key-value pair in your code. please check carefully. These type of error occurred when you violate some constraints.